# URL to image in angular js

Tags: angularjs, html

**EDIT:** TIL that you don't need to add the url in the scope. Also, to be careful with the key, thanks.

I'm trying to show some images and its names in an HTML5 doc, here's the index:

```
    <div ng-repeat="producto in productos">     
            <figure class="floating">
              <img ng-src="{{ image }}" alt="Macaque in the trees" class="rcorners3" style='width:100%;' border="0" alt="Null">
              <figcaption>{{ name }}</figcaption>
            </figure>
    </div>
```

At the top I have:

```
    <body ng-app="app"> 


<div class="main" ng-controller="app">
```

And this is how the MainController.js looks like:

```
app.controller('app', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.productos = [{
            name : 'Management Guides',
            image : url('managemant-guides.jpg')
        }, {
            name : 'Leaflets',
            image : url('managemant-guides.jpg')
        }, {
            name : 'Production Charts',
            image : url('managemant-guides.jpg')
        }, {
            name : 'Technical Guides',
            image : url('managemant-guides.jpg')
        }, {
            name : 'Poultry News',
            image : url('managemant-guides.jpg')
        }
    ];
}]);
```

I tihnk I'm failing at the ng-src point, not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using:

```
 ng-src="{{ producto.image }}"
```

Comment: Thank you, after aplying your solution I was getting a white page, saying that the URL is not defined, so I modified the array in the controller as well. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You are making a mistake. Use 'producto' as key

```
<div ng-repeat="producto in productos">     
                <figure class="floating">
                  <img  ng-src="{{ producto.image }}" alt="Macaque in the trees" class="rcorners3" style='width:100%;' border="0" alt="Null">
                  <figcaption>{{ producto.name }}"</figcaption>
                </figure>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, after aplying your solution I was getting a white page, saying that the URL is not defined, so I modified the array in the controller as well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Edit, actually ng-src="{{ producto.name }} is wrong,  no ng-src is needed for the .name, it works with just {{ producto.name}}